# How do you append to an indirect parameter expansion of an array in BASH?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I know you can create an [indirect parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to an array like so:

```
var1="target"
var2="arrayname"
targetarrayname=( "one" "two" "three" )
builtarrayname="${var1}${var2}[@]"
echo ${!builtarrayname} # prints "one two three"
```

But I can't figure out how to append to this indirect reference, as I normally would directly with `targetarrayname+=('foo')`.

I've tried:

```
!builtarrayname+=('foo') # gives "Syntax error near unexpected token `'foo''"
```

and some other random assorted attempts which are basically variations on this.

My intended output is to have `targetarrayname` contain `one two three foo`, and to have done so by indirect parameter expansion.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

var1="target"
var2="arrayname"
targetarrayname=( "one" "two" "three" )
builtarrayname="${var1}${var2}[@]"
echo ${!builtarrayname} # prints "one two three"

eval "${builtarrayname:0:-3}+=( 'foo' )"

echo ${!builtarrayname} # prints "one two three foo"
```

Do note though that eval could be considered evil :p
You need to be sure that you only have sanitized input to eval statements, to avoid the possibility of unintended code execution.

EDIT:

The `:0:-3` in `eval "${builtarrayname:0:-3}+=( 'foo' )"` removes `[@]` from the literal string that `$builtarrayname` contains. Since assignment of arrays only use the variable name, we had to remove it. ( [read more here to see how string manipulation in variables work](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) )

and no, I don't think it can be done without eval, as that's how the left side of the assignment gets resolved before the assignment occurs (see [this nice answer for more info on eval](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23111/what-is-the-eval-command-in-bash).

Comment: Much appreciated! Is there no way to do it without using `eval`?

Comment: Also, I'm struggling to understand what the `:0:-3` is doing, can you explain that for me? i.e. why does this work?

Comment: Insofar as this answer is hardcoding `'foo'` to avoid needing to answer the question of how to safely escape data before injecting it into an `eval`, it's a little bit of a dodge.

Answer (score 3):

#### With Bash 3.2 Compatibility

It avoids [substantial security bugs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) to run all values through `printf %q` to ensure that they're safely escaped before substituting them into `eval` content.

```
#!/bin/bash

appendToArray() {
  local _targetArrayName _argumentData _cmd
  _targetArrayName=$1; shift || return
  printf -v _argumentData '%q ' "$@"
  printf -v _cmd '%q+=( %s )' "$_targetArrayName" "$_argumentData"
  eval "$_cmd"
}

target=( "first item" "second item" )
appendToArray target "third item" "fourth item"
declare -p target
```

...correctly emits as output:

```
declare -a target=([0]="first item" [1]="second item" [2]="third item" [3]="fourth item")
```

---

#### For Bash 4.3+ Only

```
#!/bin/bash

appendToArray() {
  declare -n _targetArray=$1; shift
  _targetArray+=( "$@" )
}

target=( "first item" "second item" )
appendToArray target "third item" "fourth item"
declare -p target
```

...has identical output, with much less (and much simpler) code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `printf`

```
arrayname=()
arrayvariable=arrayname

printf -v $arrayvariable[1] "test"
echo "${arrayname[1]}"
```

To fill in whole array you can use a for loop

```
arrayname=()
arrayvariable=arrayname

for i in {0..5}; {
    item="$arrayvariable[$i]"
    printf -v $item "test$i"
    echo "${!item}"
}
```

Note that quotes are not necessary around var name in `printf` command because var name can't have spaces, if you try to add var with space in name it'll give you this error

```
$ printf -v 'test 1' 'sef'
bash: printf: `test 1': not a valid identifier
```

Comment: Note that inserting something at position 1 is leaving index 0 empty.

Answer (score 0):

The `declare` command takes assignments as arguments, which are expanded before the declaration. Thus, you can introduce any level of indirection when declaring variables. The following works in Bash 3.2.

```
$ array=myarray
$ declare -a "$array+=(\"element 1\")"
$ echo ${myarray[0]}
element 1
```