# How to append to Bash array without knowing name of array?

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm trying to declare and append to an array in Bash without knowing the name of the array variable. I have the name of the array stored in `$arrayvariable`, which I use to set up the array with `eval`:

```sh
arrayvariable=arrayname
eval "${arrayvariable}=( )"
```

When I go to append to the array, I use `eval` again:

```sh
eval "${arrayvariable}=( "${!arrayvariable[@]}" "mynewvalue" )"
```

However, when I print the array, I get:

```sh
echo "${arrayname[@]}"
# 0 mynewvalue
```

Why is the value of the array `( 0 mynewvalue )` and not just `( mynewvalue )`? How would I append to my array without knowing the name of it? Perhaps `eval` is not the way to go here?

I'm using Bash 3.2.57 because I need my script to be compatible with the majority of macOS versions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56964941/how-do-you-append-to-an-indirect-parameter-expansion-of-an-array-in-bash is duplicative, but its answer is out of date. I'll add a new one there when I get a chance.

Comment: Oh, bash 3.2. Nevermind, you *need* the out-of-date answer, so the duplicate is perfect as-is.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks, that question's answer solves this in the short term, but I'd love to find an answer which doesn't rely on `eval` and is compatible with Bash 3.2

Comment: You're not going to be able to find one (if bash 3.2 was capable of that, there wouldn't have been a reason to introduce namevars in 4.3), but I can at least write one that's more careful about *how* it uses `eval`. I'll @-notify you here after I've written one on the duplicate.

Comment: I've now added my own answer on the other question. The bash-3.2-compatible variant it contains still uses `eval`, but it's a lot more careful (and thus safer) about how it does so.